# Deploy Zip Package to Azure as Web App

Tags: azure, deployment, .net

Having a Visual Studio project to deploy to Azure from Jenkins running on GNU/Linux, I'd like to prepare a package with MSBuild in Windows. Something like `MSBuild my.csproj /T:Package`. This will create a zip file.

Now, how can I deploy this file to an Azure Web App instance over ftp? I was hoping just putting the file in wwwroot would unpack it, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any good suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use Powershell Plugin for Jenkins and install Azure Powershell on build servers. Here's a nice guide:

[Devops on Windows with Jenkins and Azure Resource Manager](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikerichter/2016/06/29/devops-on-windows-with-jenkins-and-azure-resource-manager/)

From here, you can easily deploy the zip using the cmdlet below:

```
Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name site1 -Package .\WebApplication1.zip
```

You can find more information about this cmdlet [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicemanagement/azure.compute/v3.1.0/publish-azurewebsiteproject).